# Is there Leader for raiders, gunners and other such hostile NPC units

Tags: fallout-4

I had played Fallout: New Vegas and after completing main story, in narration it was said that raiders with their leader figure survived in northern area.

I want to know if in Fallout 4, do the hostile NPCs have leaders whom we can kill or maybe do missions for?

For example, Mirelurk Queen at The Castle.

Comment: I believe you're referring to the Great Khans, which were a distinct faction, not random raiders. Papa Khan was *not* the leader of the "raiders".

Answer (score 3):

Some do, some don't, it really depends on the group. There's a group of bandits held up in the auto factory with a leader named Jared. There's eventually a quest to kill him, but even if you don't take the quest, he's there.

Other groups are just bandits with no leader. My guess would be that if there's a named leader, there's probably a quest to kill him/her at some point in the game.

Comment: There are many raider settlements with named leaders. But someone who is like the main guy of raiders in boston.

Comment: I've not come across any such person. I doubt the raiders are that organized -- they just have roving bands rather than a big convention to elect their leaders. :)

Comment: Agreed — no, Fallout 4 doesn’t have an ending that tells you if entire populations survived or not. In fact, even groups with named leaders don’t really go away forever when you kill the leader: For example, the Forged eventually regenerate at their base.